# IntelliJ IDEA Pin Structure View

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to pin the `structure` view of a Class **A.java** while editing class **B.java**? (The structure window seems to follow always the focused file, and I'm unable to pin the structure view)

Comment: Class in Structure tab is always synced with the Editor tab. `Autoscroll From/To Source` works only for methods.

Comment: Yep... I think it would be much more useful if I were able to check the API of a different class

Comment: Open a feature request at Jetbrains, and I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature yet. I submitted a request for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203853